# Using unobtrusive Ajax but still running Javascript of the page being fetched

Tags: jquery, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive

I want to start with pages that work without Javascript, then add Javascript fanciness and finally add some bits of Ajax.

This all seems to keep stuff clean, I was very happy with my first experiments with it. Then I ran into the following problem for which I don't see a nice solution. For these 2 example pages:

```
<!-- /products/ -->
<ul>
    <li>
        Product A thumbnail
        <a href="/details/1/">Details for A</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        Product B thumnail
        <a href="/details/2/">Details for B</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- /details/<id>/ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/details.js/"></script>
show details about the product with the given id
details.js will unobtrusively enhance it
```

#### The functionality I want

Use Ajax to dynamically load some of the details for a product on the `/products/` page, for example when hovering over the thumbnail. More precisely, fetch and show a simplified version of the `/details/<id>/` on the `/products/` page.

#### The unobtrusive implementation

When hovering a photo, make an Ajax request for the `href` attribute of the corresponding anchor. The server can respond with the full `/details/<id>/` page and a JQuery selector can cut just the interesting parts. Alternatively, the server could see that the request is special and just return the interesting parts. So far so good, easy and clean.

#### The problem

The `/details/<id>/` page is more than just HTML. It also had its own Javascript to make it fancy, therefore I want to reuse that Javascript in the `/products/` page. So I want `/products/` to fetch not just the HTML from `/details/<id>/` but also replicate the Javascript behaviour that is present on the fully fledged `/details/<id>/` page.

#### The only (bad) solution I could think of

Write explicit code to replicate what the browser does when loading a page: fetch `/details/<id>/`, look for all `<script>` tags, fetch that Javascript, trigger the on load handlers. That's a lot of boilerplate stuff that seems hard to get right. I clearly don't want to write it as the result would be anything but simple.

I also feel like it's the kind of problem that appears very often if you truly stick to unobtrusive Ajax and that there must be a more elegant solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Architecturally, a cleaner solution would be to have an Ajax call that would return just the product data (could use XML or JSON representation) rather than getting HTML and trying to cull product data from it.  The goal is to separate the data from the presentation.  A technique I've used for similar scenarios (detail appearing on mouseover) is to have an HTML 'template' that gets included in the page but hidden.  On mouseover, make your Ajax call to retrieve the product data (I usually cache the data so that subsequent mouseovers for the same item don't have to re-retrieve the data), populate your HTML template, position it, then show it.

If you're concerned about duplicating JavaScript, perhaps the JavaScript should be moved to separate files that can be included.  If the JavaScript is very page specific, then perhaps it needs to be made more general/reusable.  Or perhaps you should be using CSS and/or server-side technologies rather than JavaScript to 'make it fancy'.